# About the convergence of a sequence in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative functions such that $\int f_n d\mu=1$ for all $n$, and $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$. Let $p>1$. Is it then true that $f_n^p\to f^p$ in $L^1$?

Comment: $f_n^p$ and $f^p$ need not even be *in* $L^1$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: Sorry, I should have mentioned that $f_n,f\in L^p$. Should the assertion be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Because as Chris remarks above, $f_n^p$ needn't be in $L^1$.

For example: If the concerned measure space is $\mathbb R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-field and the Lebesgue measure and $f$ is as defined below:$$\begin{cases}x<0&f(x)=0\\0<x\le1&f(x)=1\\1+\frac1{2^{p+1}}+...\frac1{(n-1)^{p+1}}<x\le1+\frac1{2^{p+1}}+...\frac1{n^{p+1}}&f(x)=n\\1+\frac1{2^{p+1}}+...\frac1{n^{p+1}}+...<x&f(x)=0\end{cases}$$

So on an interval of length$\displaystyle \frac1{n^{p+1}}$, $f$ has value $n$, so the $L^1$ norm is the sum $\sum\frac1{n^p}$ which converges for $p>1$.

But $f^p$ is $n^p$ on the respective intervals. So its $L^1$ norm is $\sum\frac1n$ which diverges!

Comment: Thank you. In my problem, actually, $f_n$ and $f$ are in $L^p$. In which case, can the assertion be true?

Comment: So $f_n$ and $f$ are in $L_p$. Are you trying to check whether $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L_p$ implies convergence of ${f_n}^p\rightarrow f^p$ in $L_1$?

Comment: No. $f_n\to f$ in $L_1$ implies $f_n^p\to f^p$in $L_1$.